# Sources for historical financial ratios?

Tags: equities, historical-data, fundamentals

I wanted to know if there are any sources for historical financial ratios for Indian equities?
If yes please share.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure what you need. Have you tried on [Damodaran](http://pages.stern.nyu.edu/%7Eadamodar/)? He has data divided by regions and industries. What in particular do you need?

Comment: I need common financial ratios like PE, PB, EV/EBITDA those stuff for indian equities on monthly or yearly basis

Comment: If you are searching something free, I only know the existence of Macrotrends.net, where they have P/E and other ratios for selected equities. You can sort by country. 12 Equities are listed for India which should have quarterly data on ratios.